# Presto/Athena - query to discover JSON attribute frequencies?

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, presto

I have defined a Hive table where a single column contains JSON text:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS my.rawdata (
  json string
)
PARTITIONED BY (dt string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
   'separatorChar' = '\n',
   'quoteChar' = '\0',
   'escapeChar' = '\r'
)
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION 's3://mydata/';
```

Is there a Presto/Athena query that can list out all field names that occur within the JSON and their frequency (i.e. total number of times the attribute appears in the table)?

Comment: P.s. The table definition is a mess. OpenCSVSerde? quoteChar? escapeChar?

Comment: OpenCSVSerde was the one of the options provided by Athena. I'm now using `org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe` but it doesn't really make any difference. For quoteChar and escapeChar I just needed a character not present on the file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [JSON](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/json.html) functions to parse the JSON and turn it into a map. Then extract the keys and [unnest](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/sql/select.html#unnest) them. Finally, use a normal SQL aggregation:

```sql
SELECT key, count(*)
FROM (
  SELECT map_keys(cast(json_parse(json) AS map(varchar, json))) AS keys
  FROM rawdata
)
CROSS JOIN UNNEST (keys) AS t (key)
GROUP BY key
```

Comment: Limited to a single level documents

Comment: P.s. No need for a sub-query, the UNNEST can be executed on the expression aliased by `keys`

Comment: This works beautifully. The other answer using regex does not handle escaped quotes correctly.

Answer (score 0):

- Supports multi-levels documents
- Ignores keys of nesting elements

---

```
select    key
         ,count(*)
from      t cross join 
          unnest (regexp_extract_all(json,'"([^"]+)"\s*:\s*("[^"]+"|[^,{}]+)',1)) u (key)
group by  key
;
```

Comment: Works well, powerful. Feels wrong using regex on json, although in this question the `json` field is really a varchar type (hive string) so regex is probably appropriate for that datatype. Table definition is a mess as you pointed out.

Comment: Also, this answer trades the limitation of single-level in the other answer with the danger that if the same key appears in multiple levels in the json, the result will be incorrect.